# Exception in hibernate sample program

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I'm trying a sample hibernate program, to connect to MS SQL DB and execute some sql.
I've created hbm and cfg.xml files but while executing I'm getting following exception.

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:545)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2101)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1325)
    at com.persistent.demo.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:12)
    at com.persistent.demo.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:15)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.persistent.demo.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:14)
    at com.persistent.demo.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:15)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found: net.sf.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
```

I'm not getting whether I have missed any jar files or is there any other problem.
Please help.

Thanks.
-Uday

Comment: can you please post what are the jars are there in your classpath ?

Comment: it seems is a problem with your driver.
post your hibernate.cfg.xml too please.

Comment: Following jar files are there:
antlr-2.7.5H3.jar,
antlr-2.7.6rc1.jar,
asm.jar,
c3p0-0.8.5.2.jar,
cglib-2.1.3.jar,
cglib-2.1.jar,
dom4j-1.6.1.jar,
dom4j-1.6.jar,
hibernate3.jar,
javassist-3.4.GA.jar
jta.jar,
log4j-1.2.9.jar,
oscache-2.1.jar,
oscache-2.2.jar,
slf4j-api-1.5.2.jar,
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.2.jar,
swarmcache-1.0rc2.jar,
mysql-connector-java-3.1.7-bin.jar

Answer (score 2):

`Dialect class not found: net.sf.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect`

You need to put the Jar, containing this class, in your class paht.

**May the problem is, that the dialect you need is: `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect` which is aviable in the hibernate core jar.**

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have added hibernate3.jar which contains the SQLServerDialect class in it. But no use. It still showing same exceptions.

Comment: Pay attention, this are two different classes, one `net.sf.hibernate` one `org.hibernate`.

Answer (score 0):

have you add Mssqlserver.jar in your class path . or check your connection url

Comment: Mysqlserver.jar is not there but inplace of it I have "mysql-connector-java-3.1.7-bin.jar"

Comment: i wrote Mssqlserver.jar not Mysqlserver.jar oky

Comment: your goning to connect with MsSql db so use jar for that, not for mysql db.

Comment: oh sorry, my mistake.. I'll add that jar and try.. Thanks a lot.